# setting each bit in std_msg::Int8 rather the whole byte?

Tags: ros, std-msgs, binary

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I at the moment trying to come up with a solution such that I can set my std_msgs::Int8 bitwise instead of setting the whole byte.

The reason why i want to do that is because, i am currently using the message type as a register, in which the 4 last bits is read by a node, that performs certain actions based on that value.

is it possible to do something like `std_msg::Int8 msg.data[0] = True`  and thereby only set  one bit?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247872/setting-each-bit-in-std_msg::int8-rather-the-whole-byte?/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your exact syntax is incorrect, but you can definitely set individual bits and decode the number in a subscriber. For example, something like `msg.data = 8` would set the data field to have `0b00001000` in binary. You can set values using hex/binary/decimal (see [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)), and you can also use [C++ bitwise operators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html) to set and access individual bits.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, that is not possible, as the semantics of an `std_msgs/Int8` are such that it is considered a single, 8 bit integer value, not a set of individual bits.

You have two options:

1. use a message that contains a (fixed size) set of the `bool` primitive type
2. use [bit manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) to set individual bits in an `Int8`

Note that option 1 will not make ROS automagically consider the (fixed size) set of `bool`s an integer, but it is the only way to (re)set individual boolean values in a ROS message.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2